# Turn hist2d output into contours in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, distribution, contour

I have generated some data in Python using matplotlib.hist2d.  An example of the data is seen below. [image: data]

As you can see this data has some contours in it found by tracing the same color throughout the plot.  I see a gamma distribution centered around 0.015.  I would like to take this data and gather these contours so I can see a line trace through each color level.  I tried playing around with the contour function as here

```
counts, xedges, yedges, Image = hist2d(x, y, bins=bins, norm=LogNorm(), range=[[0, 1], [0, 400]])
contour(counts)
```

but that didn't seem to produce anything.

Does anyone know the best way to get these contours?  Ideally I'd like to take these contours and fit a function (like a gamma function) to them and then get the function parameters.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So the problem is that the image created by `hist2d` is plotted in data coordinates, but the contours you are trying to create are in pixel coordinates. The simple way around this is to specify the `extent` of the contours (i.e. rescale/reposition them in the x and y axes).

For example:

```
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

x = np.random.normal(5,10,100000)
y = np.random.normal(5,10,100000)
counts,ybins,xbins,image = hist2d(x,y,bins=100,norm=LogNorm())
contour(counts,extent=[xbins.min(),xbins.max(),ybins.min(),ybins.max()],linewidths=3)
```

Will produce:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed to see.  The only tweak I had to make was instead of calling contour(counts,extent=[xbins.min(),xbins.max(),ybins.min(),ybins.max()],linewidths=3), I needed the call contour(counts.transpose(),extent=[xbins.min(),xbins.max(),ybins.min(),ybins.max()],linewidths=3)

Comment: @ebarr that's nice. But If I got a 3D random-dataset(x,y,z), then how can it be possible to apply this method ?

Comment: @ebarr in mine the returned `xbins` <-> `ybins`

Comment: @diffracteD - you need to replace `x` and `y` with your real data..? What is your `z`?

Answer (score 11):

Would prefer to post this as a comment, but don't have the reputation, so ...

@ebarr has a nice solution with one small correction: the xbins and ybins coming from the 2d plot should be reversed (see matplotlib documentation, https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d
)

Also, only mildly annoying, but the contour lines colors won't line up with the colors in the 2d histogram since the histogram colorscale has been log transformed.  To fix this you can manually specify levels for the contour plot.

Making these changes, and separating the plots for clarity yields:

```
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.normal(5,10,100000)
y = np.random.normal(5,10,100000)
plt.subplot(121)
counts,xbins,ybins,image = plt.hist2d(x,y,bins=100
                                      ,norm=LogNorm()
                                      , cmap = plt.cm.rainbow)
plt.colorbar()
plt.subplot(122)
plt.contour(counts.transpose(),extent=[xbins[0],xbins[-1],ybins[0],ybins[-1]],
    linewidths=3, cmap = plt.cm.rainbow, levels = [1,5,10,25,50,70,80,100])
```

This produces:
Histogram and contour map
[image: Histogram and contour map]